# Upvoting/Downvoting on "We're Hiring" advertisements

Tags: bug, advertising

I can't change what my vote is for the advertisements on Stack Overflow.

For example, there was an ad with a guy wearing a horse mask, and I intended to downvote it but accidentally hit Upvote. I tried to change it to down but it didn't respond, and just showed the "Upvoted" icon.

Is this intentional, for whatever reason?

**EDIT:** I have nothing against the horse mask ad – I just needed an example.

Comment: One does not simply downvote the horse mask.

Comment: You... you animal.

Comment: Dude, that's not a horse, it is a weaponized pony.  Know [your memes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/144883).

Comment: OK IM SORRY GUYS I LIKE THE HORSE JEEZ

Comment: I didn't know I could vote on ads. Where are the buttons?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Upper right, when you hover